# Use the first part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find the derivative of the function:

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x70ti.jpg)Use the first part of the F.T.C. to find the derivative of the function: $$F(x)=\int_x^{10} tan (t) \,dt$$

Comment: I've alredy "solved" this problem but I wanna know if the answer is correct.

Comment: What is the answer then? Just incorporate  your attempts in the question itself.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x70ti.jpg this is a photo of what I did.

Comment: In my answer I changed the " t " for the angle symbol because I don't know how to type it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is wrong. And it's not an answer to the question that you posted, since the question that you posted is about $\int_{10}^x\tan t\,\mathrm dt$, whereas at the answer that you posted you switched the $x$ with the $10$.

Anyway, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F'(x)=\tan x$.

Comment: Yes I know that I switched the limits, that's why I put an (-) in front of the integral. And I didn't use the same symbol because I didn´t know how to type it but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @VirginiaMartínHerrera But do you get why your answer is wrong? It has nothing to do with the switching.

Comment: No I don't. The answer must be $$tan(x)$$ but because it is the integral between 10 and x the answer is $$tan 10 - tan x$$

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that if $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$, then $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Now I get it! Thank you! I forgot I had the differential in front of the integral which means I just have to put $$tan (u)$$